# ArrayList changing when receiving info from socket Java

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, datagram

I am getting this bug which I just can't imagine the cause for.  I have a receiver class which receives packets, within which is an ArrayList.  No, the packets don't have an ArrayList; the class has one.  When I receive a new packet, the ArrayList is altered, but before I alter it.  In fact, before I even read the data from the packet into the object I am using the data.  Not only that, but the ArrayList is changing all the objects within the array to the equivalent of the object which is created from the data in a later instruction...

Method which is producing the weird behaviour:

```
public void processPackets() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    try {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Start:  " + outBuffer);

            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println("Before: " + outBuffer);

            // Find out where the packets are coming from
            if (sendHost == null) {
                sendHost = packet.getAddress();
                sendPort = packet.getPort();
            }

            // Grab the data from the packet
            PacketInfo data = new PacketInfo(packet.getData());
            System.out.println("Found: " + data);

            if (this.packetWithinWindow(data.getSequenceNumber())) {
                outBuffer.add(data);
                System.out.println("After:  " + outBuffer);
            }
            ackThePacket(data);

            if (processData()) {break;}; // Returns true after last packet processed

            System.out.println("End:  " + outBuffer);
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println(ioe);
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Given that outBuffer is an `ArrayList<PacketInfo>` and `PacketInfo.toString()` returns a sequence number and a list of the first 20 bytes, this is a sample of the weird behaviour that is then printed to the console (after several cycles through the code where outBuffer starts empty):

```
Start:  []
Before: []
Found: 
2 [-120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120]
After:  [
2 [-120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120]]
End:  [
2 [-120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120]]
Start:  [
2 [-120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120, 8, 0, 2, -120]]
Before: [
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48]]
Found: 
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48]
After:  [
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48], 
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48]]
End:  [
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48], 
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48]]
Start:  [
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48], 
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 71, 68, 70, 68, 48]]
Before: [
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Found: 
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
After:  [
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
End:  [
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This is perplexing me so any help is appreciated.  If it's any help, this is compiled using Java 6.

Comment: Well you're repeatedly using the same byte array, unless your `PacketInfo` constructor (which you haven't shown) copies the data.

Comment: Aha!  That should be it!  I keep forgetting that regular arrays are reference types too, given their primitive-like treatment in so many aspects.  Thanks for that!